# Handling invalid input in extension of IQueryable.OrderBy using string object member names

Tags: c#

I wrote an extension method to IQueryable OrderBy (and OrderByDescending, ThenBy and ThenByDescending), which all call my function CreateExpression to get the expression for sorting.

Problem is if someone calls this method with an invalid parameter, for example a string which is not a member name in the object type being sorted. That's why I check if pi is not null. Now I need to return something other than null if the parameter was invalid and pi is null, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. I would like to return an expression without sorting, is that possible and how would I do that?

```
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string orderBy)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderBy))
        {
            var resultExp = CreateExpression(source, "OrderBy", orderBy);
            return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
        }
        else
        {
            return source;
        }
    }


    private static MethodCallExpression CreateExpression<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string methodName, string orderBy)
    {
        if (methodName != "OrderBy" && methodName != "OrderByDescending" && methodName != "ThenBy" && methodName != "ThenByDescending")
            methodName = "OrderBy";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderBy))
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(orderBy);

            if (pi != null)
            {
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
                MemberExpression me = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, pi);
                var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(me, parameter);

                return Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                    new Type[] { typeof(T), pi.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
            }
        }

        //todo
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You CodingYoshi and Simon Katanski, both of your replies are quite excellent. I ended up throwing an exception, since I cannot affect changing the string parameter into expressions. I wish I could mark both answers but I'll mark Simons answer as that's something I'd do if I could get rid of the string parameter. However then I don't think I'd need to write an extension method in the first place, I could use the default implementation of OrderBy directly. Thanks!

Comment: you can still use your extension method:
private static MethodCallExpression CreateExpression<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string methodName, string orderBy)

Just instead of orderBy you can use an expression - just a small optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential solution would be to use a property expression like this. Pass a property selector into your method, instead of a string:

```
Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertySelector
```

Inside of your method you can get the name of your property and use it just like in your code:

```
private static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertySelector)
{
    MemberExpression member = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
    PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    return propInfo.Name;
}
```

Your method signature would look like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertySelector)
```

And you could call it this way:

```
collection.OrderBy(p => p.UserName)
```

You'll get static typing, and you can remove the magic string.

Otherwise, than that - I'd throw an InvalidOperationException, given it's an invalid situation and the user of your code should be informed about it with an exception - rather than the code silently failing.

Comment: You do not gain anything using this approach because `IEnumerable` already has the capability to do `collection.OrderBy(p => p.UserName)`. So you get nothing extra from this approach.

Comment: But you can pass the methodName in as well and then you get a better implementation of what crazysnake wanted.

Comment: Sure but what do you gain? You can do `OrderByDescending` with Linq already and you will get compiler support. Here you will pass a func and then a string and for the string there will be no compiler support. Thus is it really worth it?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding - your code gains one statically typed property selector instead of a magic string one. Nothing else really changes.

Comment: Ok I will stop with this message. The gain which you speak of is already available in Linq. Nothing wrong with your answer but letting you know.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have written your extension method to work with any type (you have no constraints), the only option you have is to throw an exception if the user has provided you with a property name that does not exist. There is not much else you can do.

However, if you apply a simple constraint to `T`, then you can use that to provide a default sort in the case wherein the provided property does not exist. Here is how:

1. Create an interface and have all your `T`s implement the interface:

   ```
   public interface IOrderable
   {
       int Id { get; }
   }
   ```
2. Change your extension and apply a constraint to it. Then if you do not find the provided property name, return an expression which will sort on the `Id` column by default:

   ```
   private static MethodCallExpression CreateExpression<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string methodName, string orderBy)
       where T : IOrderable
   {
       // your code...

       //here is the todo
       // Here we are returning an expression which will sort on the 
       // Id column by default
       var parameterDef = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
       PropertyInfo piDef = typeof(T).GetProperty(nameof(IOrderable.Id));
       MemberExpression meDef = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterDef, piDef);
       var orderByExpDef = Expression.Lambda(meDef, parameterDef);
       return Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                   new Type[] 
                   {
                       typeof(T), piDef.PropertyType
                   }, 
                   source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpDef));
   }
   ```